# How to upload file with codeigniter-restserver?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am try upload the file with Postman,but get the wrong message:`You did not select a file to upload.` I do not know what is the reason, but also trying to find ways.

#### Look at the gif of Postman:

[image]

#### Look at the php code:

```
 public function upload_post()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000",
        'max_height' => "768",
        'max_width' => "1024"
    );

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->set_response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
    else
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->response($error, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Look at the html:

```
<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('api/example/upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

#### Upload file with the browser is OK!

[image]

#### Two code is OK！Browser upload no problem！But can not upload with Postman!

#### Has been solved, the original is not added `$this->upload->do_upload('file')` and key `file` postman.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

could you put your form code ? i think you forgot to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'`